# The use of "stand emphasizing"

Tags: phrase-usage, gerunds, parsing

I asked a [duplicated question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117836) in another SE site. A native speaker left the following comment:

> It is somewhat of a duplicate, but the answer to this question, while
>   given in the accepted answer to the other question, is just barely
>   mentioned and could **stand emphasizing** in that or another answer.

I found this bolded use very peculiar, so I did a little search in Google Books. However, almost all examples are fake ones, like ".. stand, emphasizing ..", ".. took a stand emphasizing ..", etc.

Except for only this one:

> A few points brought out by Dr. Smith in my opinion will **stand
>   emphasizing**: First. A constant and even flow of the gases. Second.
>   Warm gases.
>
> -- *[Oral Hygiene, Volume 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=vbs1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA398&lpg=PA398&dq=stand%20emphasizing)*

Is this a rarely used turn of phrase?

Does *stand* here mean *'to remain valid, effective, or unaltered'*, as in 'the agreement stands' or *'be in a specified state or condition'*, as in 'I stand corrected'?

And how to assess the syntactic function of 'emphasizing' here, a non-finite clause or a complement?

Comment: I notice that *Oral Hygiene, Volume 3* was published in 1913, so some of the usage in that book is likely to sound a little dated now.  As J.R. says below, it's more common to say "could stand" than "will stand" now.

Comment: I just felt a flow of warm gases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the first meaning: 'to remain valid, effective, or unaltered', though I would gloss it as "survive".

"Emphasizing" is a non-finite clause, used here in a middle sense: "stand being emphasized" would be a passive form with the same meaning.

Making it more confusing is that this construction "X could stand being Y" is a litotes: the literal meaning is "X would not be harmed by Y being done to it", but the actual meaning is "X would be improved by Y", or, more succinctly, "Y should be done to X".

Comment: Can I say 'this room will stand refurbishing', or 'the answer could stand being added a few examples, or 'slavery will stand abolishing'?

Comment: @KinzleB - I think "**will** stand" sounds awkward in these constructs. It's usually heard in hypothetical situations, like: _this room could stand a refurbishing_ (meaning, _it wouldn't hurt to refurbish this room_, which means, _this room would look better if it was refurbished)_. The slavery example doesn't work, either, because _could stand_ is a way of talking about a nicety, not a moral condition. So: _"We could all stand a raise around here"_ is okay, if we think we're a little underpaid, but: _"This nation could stand to abolish slavery"_ sounds like the wrong choice of words.

Comment: @J.R.I found one example: It is, in other words, the psychological moment to execute repairs on any business that **will stand refurbishing.** But I will not use it myself on your suggestion. :)

Comment: @KinzleB: We can say "This tree could stand trimming".  But if we say "This tree could stand cutting down", or "could stand to be cut down", it means the landscape or the vista or whatever would be better off if the tree were to be cut down. The tree would be improved by being cut down. A kind of irony. It's like the scene in Herzog's *Aguirre, Zorn Gottes* where Don Lope says to one of his henchman words to the effect that another man, who has been giving him some trouble, "could stand to be a head shorter".

Comment: Gerunds or infinitives don't make a difference in these construct? @TRomano

Comment: @KinzleB: I don't think there's a discernible difference in meaning.  This car could stand washing. This car could stand to be washed.

Comment: Is an indefinite article optional? Say, the car could stand **a** washing. @TRomano

Comment: @KinzleB - Nice find! But that quote is from 1920. It could be that the general usage has shifted for some reason. Very interesting stuff, to be sure.

Comment: I don't find anything odd about "will stand refurbishing".